# Laravel change stored value of polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make the stored value of a polymorphic relationship more readable by other applications. Currently the polymorphic model type is stored as the FQCN of the model. Using the example in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations), imageable_type could be "App\Product", or "App\Staff". However, this value can be a little more difficult to manage if any non-laravel applications which aren't based on this convention and are also accessing the same database. Also, if the model FQCN ever gets refactored, you have to modify your other applications to account for the change.

Is there a way to change the type to something more consistent and readable, and then have a mapping class that maps the keys to the model? (e.g. have "product" map to "App\Product")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. This is a change that was [recently](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9891) implemented.

---

Add this to your service provider (in the `boot` method):

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::morphMap([
    'product' => App\Product::class
]);
```

If you simply pass an array of model names, [it'll default to using the table names](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10147):

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::morphMap([
    App\Product::class,
    App\Staff::class,
]);
```

Comment: These days, you can even just put $morphClass on your model.

Comment: @CaptainHypertext - that doesn't work properly. Using it will lead you down a world of pain.

Comment: @JosephSilber Ok...I'm listening.  I just started working on a project that uses this method, referenced [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-polymorphic-broken), so what's wrong with it?

Comment: @CaptainHypertext - It doesn't work for the inverse. Using the example in the docs, `Tag::first()->taggable()` won't work.

Answer (score -1):

if you are adding morphMap method to service provider, you might want to use

```
'product' => \App\Product::class
```

( "\" before App),otherwise your namespace can be wrong.